Why scroll behavior different between IOS and Android in html5
// arr1 is a long Array.
const arr1 = ref<any[]>([])
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr1.value.push({
        name: i,
        key: `key-${i}`,
    })
}

const arr2 = computed(() => {
    return arr1.value.slice(start.value, start.value + 10)
})

And there is a button:
<view class="test-btn" @click="test">Test</view>

const test = () => {
    start.value = 1
}

now, render arr2 by v-for:
<view v-for="item in arr2" :key="item.key" class="item">
    {{ item }}
</view>

Case 1 :
1、Scroll the list，and make arr2[0] partially hidden ：

2、Click the test button
Android device :
arr2[1] is now at top of the page.

IOS devicce :
arr2[1] scrolled to arr2[0].

Case 2:
1、Scroll the list, and make a lot of items hidden:

2、Click the test button
Android device :
The page has no change:

IOS devicce :

Question：
What went wrong? And how to make their behavior consistent?
Here is the test project:
scroll-vue.zip
App.vue:
<template>
    <view class="content">
        <view class="test-btn" @click="test">Test</view>
        <view v-for="item in arr2" :key="item.key" class="item">
            {{ item }}
        </view>
    </view>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from "vue"

const arr1 = ref<any[]>([])
const start = ref(0)

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr1.value.push({
        name: i,
        key: `key-${i}`,
    })
}

const arr2 = computed(() => {
    return arr1.value.slice(start.value, start.value + 10)
})

const test = () => {
    start.value = 1
}
</script>

<style>
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.test-btn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.item {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>



no, I'm not downloading some rando's zip file - post the code required to demonstrate the issue

Added, Thanks~~
